# problem with CSS and div

Tags: css, html

I have some trouble getting some divs to behave as I want.

Look at these links:

- Link 1: http://tikko.nu/v1/ - two divs
- Link 2: http://tikko.nu/v2/ - one div

I want to use two divs (`.content`) without the right divs positioned wrong. How can I fix it? As you can see it works fine with one `.content` div. If I use two content divs it will be wrong as you can see on link 2.

Any suggestions on how I can solve it?

Answer (score 3):

You’ll need to add a `<div>` to hold the contents of the left column, and another `<div>` to hold the contents of the right sidebar.

At the moment, you’ve got:

- `<div id="wrapper">`

  - `<div class="content">`
  - `<div class="content">`
  - `<div class="sidebarRight">`
  - `<div class="sidebarRight">`

You need:

- `<div id="wrapper">`

  - `<div class="leftcolumn">`

    - `<div class="content">`
    - `<div class="content">`
  - `<div class="rightcolumn">`

    - `<div class="sidebarRight">`
    - `<div class="sidebarRight">`

Comment: @Bob: hooray! Floating’s complicated. Eric Meyer has a great explanation of the rules involved in *[CSS: The Definitive Guide](http://www.amazon.co.uk/CSS-Definitive-Guide-Eric-Meyer/dp/0596527330)* — it’s worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is separate the sidebar from the main content by creating a wrapper for your divs on the left and a wrapper for your div on the right.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with setting up 2 columns and thats the answer. Quick fix I believe would simply float right the two sidebars and put their divs first under wrapper.